# ¿Como se que usuario esta conectado a la base de datos? sql server

Tags: sql-server

quiero saber que usuario esta conectado a la base de datos que estoy utilizando.

Encontre esto:

```
[ @loginame = ] 'login' | session ID | 'ACTIVE'
```

pero no se como usarlo

Comment: Puedes utilizar la vista dinámica sys.dm_exec_sessions. De ella extraes el login_name. [sesiones](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-exec-sessions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No estoy seguro si deseas conocer tu usuario o los usuarios conectados a la base de datos. Dependiendo de los permisos que tengas, podrás ver o no a otros usuarios.

Para ver los usuarios conectados, puedes usar el procedimiento sp_who2. Para ver solo tu usuario, tienes distintas opciones dependiendo si quieres ver el usuario de Windows, login de la instancia o el usuario de la base de datos.

```
EXEC sp_who2;

SELECT SESSION_USER usuario_BD_sesion, 
       CURRENT_USER usuario_BD_actual, 
       SYSTEM_USER  usuario_sistema, 
       ORIGINAL_LOGIN() login_usado_inicialmente, 
       SUSER_SNAME() nombe_login_asociado_a_la_sesion;
```

Comment: Gracias con el select funciono correctamente :D